# Double and half speed for range input

Tags: javascript, math, range

I have a range input that is a speed control.  The default, starting speed, is dynamic and can change based on user input.

I want to be able to set the min and max values in relation to the starting speed, so that the slider begins in the middle of the range input.

The range is nonlinear.

How can I determine the values of min and max if, for example I wanted to have the min one third of the initial speed and the max three times as fast?

I have tried using the `Math.pow()` and `Math.log()` functions but it does not result with my slider starting in the MIDDLE of the range.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
min = initial / 3;
max = initial * 3;
middle = ( min + max ) / 2;
initalPerc =  initial / (min + max ) /;
```

Comment: `middle = initial` would be better.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer but my ````middle```` is a set value that I have to begin with, basically I want to do the opposite of your answer.  For example, I start of a middle value of ````500```` how can I figure out min/max with 500 still in the middle of the range?

Comment: Any speed can be trasformed in a percentual value, like this: perc = speed / ( min + max ). If the result is 0.3, you have covered 30% of the total bar length.

Comment: If you have a speed and you want min and max, you use the formulas I gave you. In the solution. Otherwise, it's not clear what you want. Try to make pratical examples, with value you have and value you expect

Comment: Okay I understand where you are going, so could I calculate the new speed by determining how far the slider has moved (from the middle) and multiply by the initial percent?

Comment: You can do both. If you have the slider position, you can use the the percentage of slider used, multpy it for (min + max ) and obtain the value. If you have the value, you can obtain the percentage with "value / ( min + max )" to be applied to the slider. It depends on what you have, if you have the value or the slider position